# React js : executing functions dependent on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I want to execute a function only after a state has been set.

My code is as below

```
export function Details() {

    let params = useParams();


     const certificateData = useContext(DataContext) //fetching data from the database on load
  
     const [individualData,setIndividualData] = useState([])
     const [tokenID,setTokenID] = useState('')

        
        const setIndividualDetails = async () => {
        
            setIndividualData(certificateData.find(uploadedFile => uploadedFile.QRurl === params.QRurl))    
        }
        

        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchTokenID = async () => {

                await setIndividualDetails()

                try{
                    const {data} = await axios({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: `https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/mints/${individualData.transaction_hash}?chain=polygon`,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            Authorization: '4d86xxxxxx-929e-xxxx'
                        }
                    });

                //   setTokenID(token_id)    
                    console.log(data.token_id) 

                }catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

            fetchTokenID()
        
        },[certificateData])
   


  return (

    <div>
       {individualData && (<h2>{individualData.transaction_hash}</h2>)}
    </div>
)}
```

In the above code my axios call to the api requires the paramater individualData.transaction_hash which is undefined in the intitial render and throws the undefined error

My context (DataContext) that sets the value of certificateData gets its value only on the second render, meanwhile axiox request has been called on the first render

How do I ensure the axios request runs only after individualData has got its value?
Please help

I tried a lot of async await but it does not seem to work.

***Edit after answer changed my useEffect to below and took setIndividualDetails outside***

```
  useEffect(() => {
                if (certificateData.length === 0) {
                   return;
                }
                
                setIndividualDetails()

                if (!individualData || individualData.length === 0) 
                    return;

                fetchTokenID()

             }, [certificateData, individualData]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just condition it?

```
const fetchTokenID = async () => {
   ...
};

useEffect(() => {
   // Make sure `individualData` has members.
   if (individualData.length === 0) {
      return;
   }

   // If above condition is not met, run the function as intended.
   fetchTokenID();
}, [certificateData, individualData]);
```

Here we make the `useEffect` also "watch" the value of `individualData` by including it in the dependency array.
And then basically saying only run the `useEffect` contents if the `individualData` array contains values.

I'm assuming you'd want to run `fetchTokenID` only a single time, in which case we should also handle that, since this `useEffect` will run every time the value of `individualData` changes.

This can be handled either via `useRef` that would determine if the function has already ran.

**Example:**

```
const hasFetchedRef = useRef(false);

const fetchTokenID = async () => {
   ...
};

useEffect(() => {
   // Make sure the function doesn't run more than a single time.
   if (hasFetchedRef.current) {
      return;
   }
   // Make sure `individualData` is not `null`/`undefined` and that it has members.
   if (!individualData || individualData.length === 0) {
      return;
   }

   // If above conditions are not met, run the function as intended.
   fetchTokenID();
}, [certificateData, individualData]);
```

Alternatively, maybe we could rely on the value of `tokenID` if we set it in the `fetchTokenID`.

**Example:**

```
const fetchTokenID = async () => {
   ...
   setTokenID(someValue);
   ...
};

useEffect(() => {
   // Make sure the function doesn't run more than a single time.
   if (!tokenID) {
      return;
   }
   // Make sure `individualData` is not `null`/`undefined` and that it has members.
   if (!individualData || individualData.length === 0) {
      return;
   }

   // If above conditions are not met, run the function as intended.
   fetchTokenID();
}, [certificateData, individualData]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! it dint work says length is undefined. individualData is being set inside fetchTokenID() should i try some other way?

Comment: Made some changes. The code before was also incorrect as I've misread your question. Please try this again and see if the error pops up again. Let me know if it does.

Comment: thanks so much.. where do i call the getIndividualDetails() function, since its currently inside fetchTokenID(), if i restrict the call to fetchTokenID() to getthing the value of individual data then i should place it somewhere outside?

Comment: Well you can put it in a separate `useEffect` for instance. Also, if `certificateData` has a value on init, we could simply populate `individualData` with the relevant value instead of the empty array.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot your method worked, I placed setIndividualDetails in the useEffect call itself. Edited my question with the final code